# django permalink get variable

Tags: django, permalinks

Is there a way to add get variables into the url while using permalink?

So www.example.com/1999/news/**?filter=entertainment**

Answer (score 1):

IMHO Permalink should not contain a query parameter. It doesn't quite sound right.

That said, there is a very crufty and un-Django like way to return an URL like the one you have specified from the `get_absolute_url()` method of a model.

**Steps**

First add a dummy URL and corresponding do-nothing view. For e.g.

```
# models.py
class MyModel(models.Model):
    ...
    @models.permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return ('dummy_url', [str(self.id), self.filter])

# urls.py
url(r'^news/(?P<model_id>\d+)/\?category=(?P<category>\w+)$', 
    'dummy_url', {}, name = 'dummy_url'),

# views.py
def dummy_url(request, *args, **kwargs):
    pass
```

This dummy will only serve to *generate* the URL. I.e. you will get the correct URL if you execute `instance.get_absolute_url()`.

You will have to add *another*, *proper* URL configuration and a matching view to actually display the instance page when the URL is called. Something like this.

```
# urls.py
url(r'^news/(?P<model_id>\d+)/$', 
    'correct_view', {}, name = 'correct_view'),

# views.py
def correct_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    # do the required stuff.
```

The `correct_view` will have to extract the `GET` parameter from the `request` though.

Note how similar the dummy and proper URL configurations are. Only the query parameter is extra in the dummy.

Comment: hm, wow. ok, so if i don't use a get param, then how would i be able to pass in text that may include things like space or ', etc?

Comment: See this question. It is about passing text with spaces to an URL. http://stackoverflow.com/q/3675368/140185  Also, can you not pass an id or a slug instead of the field with spaces/commas?

Comment: i'm trying to pass the name of a person.  Since it can appear as a link in places, a POST doesn't seem right.  A slug may work, but is it right to have an apostrophe in the url? That doesn't look right

Comment: IIRC slugs don't have apostrophes. At least the ones generated by `from django.template.defaultfilters.slugify` don't. So you should be safe with slugs I think.

Comment: But I guess my question is, what if I need the apostrophe? The slugs, I believe, just strips them because it's not accurate (caps, apostrophes, etc), but supposed to be a representation.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know how best to go about it in that case. I suspect that adding an URL config with both `\w` and `\W` _may_ solve your purpose.