# django url pattern for %20

Tags: django, django-urls

In Django what is the url pattern I need to use to handle urlencode characters such as %20

I am using `(?P<name>[\w]+)` but this only handles alphanumeric characters so % is causing an error

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I was able to make it work using the configuration given below. Check if it will suit your needs.

```
(?P<name>[\w|\W]+)
```

Comment: doesn't this match all word characters and all non-word characters? wouldn't `.` be much easier

Comment: @JKirchartz It's equivalent IMHO, but also just as dangerous for the same reason.

Comment: '[\w|\W]' is just the same as '.', but more confusing, so -1

Answer (score 22):

If you only want to allow space:

```
(?P<name>[\w\ ]+)
```

Comment: Much better than allowing all non-word characters. Thank you.

Comment: That's the best answer I think: the most restrictive, but still allows space

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do that and allow others chars is using '\s' that is any spaces, tabs and new lines

```
(?P<name>[\w\s]+)
```

Comment: %20 is space, I would not want t allow tabs or new lines or soft new lines, etc

Answer (score 2):

I am using Django 2.2.

It handles the %20 (which means space) in url using [Path converter: str](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/urls/#path-converters)

You simply need to use:

```
<name> or <str:name>
```

For example, following example loads view "some_view" defined in view.py

```
#urls.py
from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
   path("<name>",views.some_view),
   ....
]
```

The following function renders "some.html" after processing. In this example sending the received name to "some.html".

```
#view.py
def some_view(request, name):
    # process here
    context = { "name" : name }
    return render(request,"some.html",context)
```