# Send data from template to a view django

Tags: django, django-templates

In my application data about a entry is displayed detailing their information. You can navigate between the entries via a hyperlink. 
So far the code:

```
<a href="/parks/{{ park.id }} ">{{park.name}}</a>
```

Has been suffient in dealing with this. The id is captured in the urls.py  and onto views.py

The problem I now face is to deal with my 'location' entry. Examples of locations are 'Europe, UK', 'USA, New York'.
I know that:

```
<a href="/parks/{{ park.location }} ">{{park.location}}</a>
```

with:

```
url(r'^location/(?P<park_location>\d+)$', Location_Main),
```

won't work, due to the spaces and commas etc.

How would I resolve this?
I would also like the 'location' view and 'location' url to handle the location of a parent company say ()

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not pass pass `park.id` and then in view get the park object and then get its location:

the url:

```
url(r'^location/(?P<park_id>\d+)$', Location_Main, name="park_location"),
```

the template:

```
<a href="{% url park_location park.id %}">{{park.location}}</a>
```

the view:

```
def Location_Main(request, park_id):
    park = get_object_or_404(Park, pk=park_id)
    location = park.location
```

Alternatively send the location as `GET` parameter:

the url:

```
url(r'^location/$', Location_Main, name="park_location"),
```

the template:

```
<a href="{% url park_location %}?location={{park.location}}">{{park.location}}</a>
```

the view:

```
def Location_Main(request):
    location = request.GET.get('location')
```

Comment: This was just I was looking for.
The get request was exactly what I wanted
Thanks a lot!

Comment: +1 Using a `park.id` is an excellent suggestion. I've had this problem before and went for the solution in my answer... but your solution is much better!

Answer (score 1):

```
 url(r'^location/(?P<park_location>[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+)/$', Location_Main),
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to remove punctuation and non-english characters from the location names before using them in the url. Alternatively you can remove them when you define `park.location`.

Comment: Okay,
I want the view to then search the db and retrieve other parks in the same location.
If I remove the punctuation, how will  I preform the search?

Comment: Remove the problem characters before adding it to the db. That way when you compare them they will be the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `urlencode` template filter to escape the characters as

```
<a href="/parks/{{ park.location|urlencode }} ">{{park.location}}</a>
```

With reference to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3675368/django-url-pattern-for-20) you may have to change the url pattern as

```
url(r'^location/(?P<park_location>[\w|\W]+)$', Location_Main)
```