# django url matching non characters and charaters

Tags: django, url

suppose I have this url

```
url(r'^delete_group/(\w+)/', 'delete_group_view',name='delete_group')
```

In template
`{%url 'delete_group' 'mwas'%}`  works but when I use

`{%url 'delete_group' 'mwas 45'%}` is not working. Any way to modify the url to accept both mwas and mwas 45

Comment: If 45 is the ID of some model you're trying to delete, you're better off sending it in a POST request and using `request.post` in your view instead of parsing `request.url`.

Answer (score 1):

The issue might be your regex. The URL example you're showing has a space in it. [`\w` won't match spaces](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html). Try this instead: `r'^delete_group/([\w\s]+)/` which allows either words or spaces in multiples.

However, know that spaces are not valid in URLs and will likely get converted to `%20` or something similar. A best practice is to use hyphens where you would put a space.

I'd also point you at [this answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3675368/django-url-pattern-for-20).

Comment: thanks jbergantine  .I have got it.  how do i close this question since it is already solved am new to stack flow

Comment: I believe you can leave it open for others to reference.