# Urls in Django 1.7 when the Url Contains spaces

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

I have a an app where a user can create events. Once that event is created there is a link to the event that is supposed to go to the event details page.

The href looks like this:

```
<a href="/events/view/{{event.event_name}}">Event Details </a>
```

So a sample url looks like this:

```
http://www.example.com/events/view/Food%20Drive%20LA
```

The %20 is giving me a problem, so I can't render urls with spaces. I think that my regular expression is incorrect in my events urls.py:

```
url(r'^view/(?P<event_name>[\w%20+])$', views.event_details, name='event_details'),
```

Here is my views.py:

```
def event_details(request, event_name):
    event_name = event_name
    #...
    return render_to_response('events/event_details.html')
```

What could be the issue here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't worry about the space percent-encoding in the URL, on the django url configuration level continue thinking about it as a usual space:

```
^view/(?P<event_name>[\w\s]+)$
```

Also see:

- [django url pattern for %20](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3675368/django-url-pattern-for-20)

Answer (score 2):

`%20` is just a space, so your regex should match a space character, not a literal `%20` string.