# Preferred arguments for redirect function

Tags: python, django

Recently I decided that when user create category page then redirect to the created category page. Thing is, for this I'm not using slug or id. I'm using it like, `category_name = decode_url(category_name_url)` for `return redirect('category', blank)` ***what should be the blank?***

I tried category_name and category_name_url but both of them don't work. What should I put there?

Here's my code

```
def category(request, category_name_url):
    user = User.objects.get(username=request.user)
    category_name = decode_url(category_name_url)
    more in the below....

@login_required
def add_category(request, category_name_url):
    category_name = decode_url(category_name_url)

    category = Category.objects.get(name=category_name)

    if not request.user.is_superuser and Category.objects.filter(author=request.user).exists():
        return render(request,'main/category_already_exists.html')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        category = Category(author=request.user)
        form = CategoryForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=category)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=True)
            return redirect('category', category_name)

    else:
        form = CategoryForm()

    return render(request, 'main/add_category.html', {'form':form})
```

urls.py

```
        url(r'^category/(?P<category_name_url>\w+)/$', views.category, name='category'),
```

With what I've tried, I get add_category() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

Comment: What is `category_name_url`? You will get an error in the first line of your `add_category` view anyway as that variable is not defined.

Comment: @Selcuk it's the argument, but I get add_category() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

Comment: The argument wasn't there before you edit the question. Try `return redirect('category', args=[category_name])`

Comment: @Selcuk yes that's true, I just edited after seeing how stupid my code is..it still kinda is tho

Comment: @Selcuk it says add_category() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given), which I don't understand because I'm using category_name_url as well in category_name

Comment: Did you try my suggestion?

Comment: @Selcuk yes I have tried return redirect('category', args=[category_name]) instead of return redirect('category', category_name)...error is saying I'm not using category_name_url no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redirect uses reverse. You have a named argument, so the reverse is:

```
reverse("category",kwargs={'category_name_url':category_name})
```

And the  redirect:

```
return redirect("category",category_name_url=category_name)
```

In the function, you have to get the category name:

```
...

    if request.method == 'POST':
            category = Category(author=request.user)
            form = CategoryForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=category)
            if form.is_valid():
                category = form.save(commit=True)
                return redirect("category",category_name_url=category.category_name)
```

Django actually allows you to define the object url with any field, not just slug or id. So you can add the following method to your model:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
...
    def get_absolute_url(self):
       return redirect(reverse('category',kwargs={'category_name_url':self.category_name})
```

And then, in your form:

```
return redirect(category)
```

Note: `reverse` accepts kwargs, not **kwargs, so you have to pass an explicit dictionary. When you use redirect, an explicit named argument.

Comment: Hello can you please help me with this issue? I tried it but won't work....

Comment: What did you try, what didn't work?

Comment: thanks for the response, I'll edit the question with what I've tried

Comment: this is what I did http://dpaste.com/31CAEYQ

Comment: I get 'Category' object has no attribute 'category_name'

Comment: Please check the database: did the form saved a new category? does this record has a category_name field? This seems like some typo

Comment: yes the form is saved but not giving me the error

Comment: do you mind if we chat...would really appreciate some help

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103689/django

Comment: for reasons beyond me couldn't login to so chat. http://www.e-chat.co/room/117691

Comment: I was able to solve it with this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3675368/django-url-pattern-for-20