# Django URL dispatcher - it calls the same view to the different URL(regular expression)

Tags: python, regex, django

Hello thank you very much for reading my question post.

I have different url path patterns in urlpatterns,
but Django URL dispatcher(re-path) calls the same view( views.selected_verb) 
for the different URL expressed by Regular expression.

These urls call the same view(views.selected_verb)
http://127.0.0.1:8000/arabic/verbs/%D9%83%D8%A7%D9%86/
http://127.0.0.1:8000/arabic/verbs/%D9%83%D8%A7%D9%86/quiz/

Would love to know how to fix it(calls different views)

here is urlpatterns

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('verbs', views.verbs, name='verbs'),
    re_path(r'^verbs/(?P<verb>.+)/$', views.selected_verb, name='selected_verb'),
    re_path(r'^verbs/(?P<verb>.+)/quiz/$', views.quiz, name='quiz'),
]
```

Thank you very much again!

Comment: A quick fix would be the order of the URL patterns, try to put the 'quiz' pattern first in the list.

Comment: I tried that too, really don't get why it doesn't work as well


    re_path(r'^verbs/(?P<verb>.+)/$', views.selected_verb, name='selected_verb'),
    re_path(r'^verbs/quiz/(?P<verb>.+)/$', views.quiz, name='quiz'),

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that `.+` will match with *anything*, which includes `%D9%83%D8%A7%D9%86/quiz/`. Maybe you could try telling it something more explicit, like `[A-Z0-9%]+`. When the `q` character comes along in quiz, it will fail matching and then go to the next url pattern which should be the one you want.

So I think it should all look like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('verbs', views.verbs, name='verbs'),
    re_path(r'^verbs/(?P<verb>[A-Z0-9%]+)/quiz/$', views.quiz, name='quiz'),
    re_path(r'^verbs/(?P<verb>[A-Z0-9%]+)/$', views.selected_verb, name='selected_verb'),
]
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!
I used .+ expression because I needed to pass Arabic character in URL,
I tried your code, but because the URLs have Arabic characters, it doesn't work properly.

Comment: @HyungminCho OK, interesting. That's not what I would expect. One other thing you could try is switching the order of `quiz` and `selected_verb`

Comment: I tried that too, 
really don't get why it doesn't work as well 

re_path(r'^verbs/(?P<verb>.+)/$', views.selected_verb, name='selected_verb'), 
re_path(r'^verbs/quiz/(?P<verb>.+)/$', views.quiz, name='quiz'),

Comment: @HyungminCho OK, one more thing to check out is this link about match URL-encoded strings: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3675368/django-url-pattern-for-20](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3675368/django-url-pattern-for-20)

Comment: I tried r'^verbs/quiz/(?P<verb>[\w|\W]+)/$' this
but it does't work as well 
Thank you very much